# Django-cities exits with "killed"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to install django-cities on a server with 500mb RAM. Whenever I run:
    manage.py cities

the system exits just saying killed.

Trying to run:
    manage.py cities --import=country --force
worked, so I am guessing it is a matter of running out of memory.

To bypass, I tried to refer the package to a local copy of the cities' data file. It still didn't work.

Any ideas on how I can migrate the data without having to increase the memory on the server?

Comment: You can try increasing your swap space.

Comment: "*the system exits just saying killed.*". Check `dmesg`, you'll see references to the "OOM Killer" running and terminating a process that used too much RAM. You'll need more RAM. As kroolik says you could add swap, but it's likely to be *glacially* slow if you do this.

Comment: @kroolik, Craig Ringer, thank you. I ran dmesg and saw this in the last line:[42076.399335] Out of memory: Kill process 6575 (python) score 378 or sacrifice child
[42076.399677] Killed process 6575 (python) total-vm:464320kB, anon-rss:195044kB, file-rss:4kB Adding swap is an option, as this is to be run one single time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the suggestion to the comments, this was solved by setting up a temporary swap file.

If you are unfamiliar with it, you can follow these steps:

1. Set up the swap file

   ```
   touch /var/swap.img

   chmod 600 /var/swap.img
   ```
2. set the swap file size

   ```
   cd /var

   dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.img bs=1024k count=1000
   ```

   This will create a 1GB swap file.
3. Prepare the disk image

   ```
   mkswap /var/swap.img
   ```
4. activate the swap memory

   ```
   swapon /var/swap.img
   ```

Once this is done, you can turn off the swap image:

```
    swapoff /var/swap.img
```

More information on virtual memory and swap files can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps#4